# Persisting sales order lines in Acumatica customization code

Tags: acumatica

I'm getting errors when trying to persist SO lines in Acumatica customization code. I created a new simple PXGraph class that defines a basic SOLine view for caching and persistence.  It's simply:

```
public PXSelect<SOLine> OrderLines;
```

In custom code, it creates some SO lines in my view cache above, by doing a cache insert:

```
SOLine newOrderLineItem = lineGraph.OrderLines.Cache.Insert();
```

then using the resulting line to set its values before persistence. After adding these lines, I try to persist them.  I've tried both:

```
lineGraph.OrderLines.Cache.Persist(PXDBOperation.Insert);
```

and:

```
lineGraph.Actions.PressSave();
```

and both give errors.  The former says "'OrderDate' cannot be empty.". However, before the Persist is executed, all lines have an OrderDate value. The StackTrace shows that it's being thrown within the RowPersisting event. So sometime between the Persist() call and the default RowPersisting event (which I haven't defined), a line's OrderDate has been set to null, but I have no idea where. The latter says "'Cross-Reference' record raised at least one error", and "'Vendor/Customer' cannot be empty." However, the line's CustomerID and VendorID are not empty, and both are valid.

What can I do to either resolve these errors or persist the lines differently that actually works?

v17.209.0028

Persist() call stack:

```
   at PX.Data.PXDBDefaultAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)
   at Aktion.Acumatica.Customizations.EDI.EEdiDocInboundProcess.CreateOrderAndLineItems(EEdiStOrdHed doc, EEdiStOrdHed origDoc)
   at Aktion.Acumatica.Customizations.EDI.EEdiDocInboundProcess.CreateSalesOrder(EEdiStOrdHed doc)
```

**Update (3/16):** So I just subclassed SOLine to my own class and overrode the OrderDate property setter to trap it being set to null. This worked, but I still don't know what's trying to null it out since the call stack just tells me that its external code. In any case, now the error is "'Operation' cannot be empty.". I guess I'll keep defaulting fields and overriding setters from errors until I run out of fields -- or patience.

Comment: SOLine's OrderDate by default is taking SOOrder's OrderDate and that seems to be the reason for this issue. Do you have data view for the Sales Order of that lines?

Comment: Samvel, The SO's view is the existing SOOrderEntry graph's Document view, and it's order date also has a value.

Comment: As Samvel Petrosov mentioned you should make sure you have a view to SOOrder and the current value is set to the current order. This should make sure the SOLine defaults from SOOrder are set during insert.

Comment: Brendan, as I already mentioned, I am using the SOOrderEntry graph's Document view. For SOLine, I am using my own view because the SOOrderEntry's transaction view is too slow. I resolved the issue finally by continuing to resolve field errors one by one.  I'll post an update soon.

Comment: I thought you created your own view on your own graph? If using SOOrderEntry then you might just need to set SOOrder view current. If doing your own graph you can select current for SOOrder. Both should auto solve the field values. As for performance setting your defaults as needed and maybe even removing some attributes could help improve performance. I have dont this many times such as removing attributes that spark sub queries to other tables when i do not need that information. So I get the need to limit the entry down the the minimum to get your entry.

Comment: Brendan, I'm using my own graph and view for SOLine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue finally by continuing to resolve field errors one by one until it persisted. I had to also set SOLine fields Operation, LineType, and AutoCreateissueLine. If you're wondering why I am trying to use a separate view at all, it's for performance reasons. I have a custom page which processes EDI data and creates SOs with SOLines. The existing view can take many, many minutes for hundreds of lines. Simplifying the view has gotten it down to a minute or less so far.